# Passing parameter to SSRS url issue when parameter value have '&'

Tags: sql-server, url, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2017

I want to pass report parameters within ssrs url, but one of the values of a parameter contains `&`, so url won't work.

*example*:

```
https://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&&Category=cup&saucer&ReportYear=2008
```

In this example the is `&` in value of parameter Category.

Currently as a work around I am replacing the value which I pass to category with

```
REPLACE(CategoryParameterValue,"&","(and)")
```

and then in the dataset I am replacing (and) back to `&`. This work around works fine, but I want to check whether there is any other solution for this issue.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing `&` with `'+escape('&')+'` in the parameter value

- [SSRS URL PARAMETERS WITH ‘&’](https://richmintzbi.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/ssrs-url-parameters-with/)

Comment: `escape('&')` gives as result `%26` as i mentioned

Comment: Hi @Hadi, replacing with %26 won't work when the url is called as a popup using javascript:void(window.open()) because '%26' is converted back to '&' in the url by the function. But escape('&') works.

Comment: You're right. But you didn't mentioned thatyou are using js. +1

Answer (score 1):

The `&` must be encoded before being passed in URL. The encoded form is `%26`.

**References**

- [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)
- [Parameter contains '&' character](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8df90ea7-899c-4a3a-a327-12b11e7ae184/parameter-contains-amp-character?forum=sqlreportingservices)